# How to restrict federated user to see a secret from secrets manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, federated-identity

I want to restrict both iam users and federated users from being able to see a certain secret from the secrets manager.
For iam user i created this policy:

```
policy={
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": [
                 f"arn:aws:iam::123831926524:user/{username}",
                "arn:aws:iam::123831926524:root"
            ]},
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Resource": "*"
                    }]}
```

But for federated users, I have no idea how to restrict them.

Comment: How do they have permission to see the Secrets? Is there an `Allow` policy that gives them this permission? Can't you remove/modify the `Allow` policy instead of allow using a `Deny` policy?

Comment: This policy that I created applies only to the iam user, and restricts everyone's access to see the secret except for one user who owns that secret. But I also want to restrict federated users if possible.

Comment: Access is denied by default. How are these users getting access that you then need to use a Deny policy to override?

Comment: I create the secret in python and then attach the policy created also in python. And for example, in the CLI I am connected with the iam user test.test and from the CLI I can do get-secret-value but from the CONSOLE I cannot see and I am connected with the federated user AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_c32sb204323d5/test.test@company.com

Answer (score 0):

Just specify who is able to use the secret (separately) by specifying `resource base policy`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_resource-policies.html

Comment: I create the secret in python and then attach the policy created also in python. And for example, in the CLI I am connected with the iam user test.test and from the CLI I can do get-secret-value but from the CONSOLE I cannot see and I am connected with the federated user AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_c32sb204323d5/test.test@company.com

Comment: That federated user seems to be given "Administrator Access", which is why it can see the secret.

Comment: Do you a suggestion or another approach for do this ?